# remoteDisconnect socket.io and redis

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-redis

I'm trying to implement [socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io) with [Redis adapter](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis) in NodeJs.

Mostly it works, but sometimes I am still getting errors when trying to disconnect / connect sockets, so I think I haven't implement it correctly.

Could someone please explain what is the difference between 
`socket.disconnect();` and `io.of('/').adapter.remoteDisconnect();`

If I initialise my io with:

```
io.adapter(redisIO({
   host: config.server.redis.host,
   port: config.server.redis.port,
   requestsTimeout: config.server.redis.request_timeout
}));
```

Shouldn't then `socket.disconnect();` be aware of using redisIO? If using `remoteDisconnect` can I still capture `socket.on('disconnect', fn)` or should `remoteDisconnect` be called in `socket.on('disconnect', fn)`?

What happens if client disconnects? How can I propagate it to socket.io cluster?

Any working examples will be appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Capture the socket event `disconnecting`, not `disconnect`, by then it's too late!

```
socket.on('disconnecting', () => {
  var room_name = sess.id
  io.of('/').adapter.remoteDisconnect(room_name, true, err => {
     delete socket.rooms[room_name]
     socket.removeAllListeners()
  })
})
```